# clean url generate GET method laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

When i submit a GET method form url generate like :

```
example.com/machine?brand=xx&model=2016&color=red&km=110
```

But i want to generate url like :

```
example.com/machine/xx/2016/red/km=110
```

My Route :

```
Route::get('/machine/{brand}/{model}/{color}/{km}',['as'=>'machine.search','uses'=>'searchController@searchmachine']);
```

Form :

```
{!! Form::open(['route'=>'machine.search','method'=>'GET','class'=>'form-horizontal','role'=>'form']) !!}
```

Comment: And how do you generate that URL? Not the route, that's for sure.

Comment: my form : {!! Form::open(['route'=>'machine.search','method'=>'GET','class'=>'form-horizontal','role'=>'form']) !!}

Comment: Is not a good practice how you do the route, is not a good way to specify the slugs like this.

Comment: But that's the way GET requests are built. Your only choice is to capture the submit event of the form and then change the action of the form to the one you like, and then submit.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do it in JS. Here is the form

```
<form action="machine">
    <input name="brand"/>
    <input name="model"/>
    <input name="color"/>
    <input name="km"/>

    <button type="submit" onclick="window.location.href=this.form.action + this.form.brand.value + this.form.model.value + this.form.color.value + this.form.km.value;">
        Submit
    </button>
</form>
```

The submit button will generate the url

```
http://website.com/machine/brandvalue/modelvalue/colorvalue/kmvalue
```

In your case, you readapt your form by replacing `route` by `url` because using `route` would require you to pass parameters

```
{!! Form::open(['url'=>'machine','method'=>'GET','class'=>'form-horizontal','role'=>'form']) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using a good practice for doing your search, at first your route must look like this:

```
Route::get('/machine/search',['as'=>'machine.search','uses'=>'searchController@searchmachine']);
```

Then in your searchController:

```
class searchController extends Controller {

    public function searchmachine(Request $request)
    {
        $brand = $request->brand;
        $model = $request->model;
        $km    = $request->km;
        $color = $request->color;

        //Do your things.
    }
}
```

And this should work:

```
example.com/machine/search?brand=xx&model=2016&color=red&km=110
```